# Row-wise processing of tensors in a batch

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I need to get the outer product of each row of a tensor separately. The code goes like:

input1=K.placeholder(shape=(None, 12))
prod=K.map_fn(someMethod,input1)

the someMethod needs to do the following:

```
*def someMethod(x):*
    ## get the outerproduct row-wise of input1 #
    outer=x*x.T
    ## subtract the identity matrix from the outer product #
    diff=outer-np.eye(12) 
    ## and return the trace of the difference matrix #
    trace=np.trace(diff)
    return trace
```

I expect the trace value to be a scalar but the prod to be a list of input of the batch size? I am using plaidml as the backend, therefore, would like something working with numpy or keras backend to work, or perhaps tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.

For row-wise outer-product of matrix A use the following:

```
outer_product = np.matmul(A[:,:,np.newaxis], A[:,np.newaxis,:])
```

Comment: np.matmul gave errors, but 
A[:,:,np.newaxis]*A[:,np.newaxis,:]
worked with tensorflow backend, but PlaidML has issues negotiating with None as index size.
I am looking for the ML implementation for the issue as tensorflow execution is very slow and I don't have an Nvidia gpu.

Comment: Could you share your code on Colab so that we can observe the problem together?

Comment: ok. 

[Colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/168ktU3t3pBIssZ-z4iy2ttaw2ndw7Ycg#scrollTo=1EA_hUw1vvPo) _italic_ **bold**

I want the code to work with plaidml backend. I somehow got it working for tensorflow.

Comment: I requested your permission.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/168ktU3t3pBIssZ-z4iy2ttaw2ndw7Ycg

Answer (score 0):

The following example performs the requested operation on a tensor `x` of shape `[None, None]` (variable batch size and variable vector dimensions). It has been tested in Tensorflow 1.13.1 and 2.0RC (`tf.placeholder` must be removed for 2.0). Comments assume input shape is `[None, 12]` for explanatory purposes.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None])  # Remove for TF 2.0
# Explicitly perform batch-wise outer product using Einstein summation notation
outer = tf.einsum('bi, bj -> bij', x, x)
outer.shape
# TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(12), Dimension(12)])
diff = outer - tf.eye(tf.shape(x)[1])
trace = tf.linalg.trace(diff)
trace.shape
# TensorShape([Dimension(None)])
```

As you can see, mapping a helper function over the batch dimension of the input is not required with Tensorflow. You can learn more about `tf.einsum` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum).